# Caching dynamic images in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, rmagick

I am using the rmagick gem for generating dynamic images from a controller. The controller takes an id as a param, does a look up on a model, writes text over an existing image, and outputs it.

I have run some benchmarks comparing generating it for every request versus writing to disk and using `send_data` to output it if it already exists. I haven't noticed much of a difference in requests/second between these two methods.

Is there a best practice for caching the image or writing it to disk instead of generating it dynamically for every request? Once generated, these images would remain mostly static but I would also like the option to re-generate it after a certain time interval.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best practice is to cache generated images and allow the webserver to serve them.

Use a webserver such as Apache or Nginx in front of your Rails app, and make sure you write the image to a location where the webserver can serve it. So if your Rails route evaluates to `/dynamic_images/3.png` (which calls `dynamic_images_controller` action `show` with id=3 and format=png), write that image into `public/dynamic_images/3.png` and use `send_file` in the controller to send it.

The next time that file is requested (`/dynamic_images/3.png`), the webserver will gladly serve it (cached) and the Rails app will never get hit.

For advanced needs, like re-generating the images, and cleaning up your controller code, have a look at the [paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem.

Comment: In a production version of this setup would that mean you have Apache or Nginx running on *every* app server in front of Puma or whatever is running Rails?

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea (never tried): why not store images (especially the ones that are dynamically generated) with memache?

Rails.cache.write("MY_IMAGE", image)

Comment: I actually like this option a lot.  See [RailsCasts #115](http://railscasts.com/episodes/115-caching-in-rails-2-1)

Comment: Memcache's max key size is 1MB by default, and, from what I remember, it doesn't do so great caching large objects (bucket sizing / resizing, though it may have been fixed by now). It's probably a bad choice for images. Also, this means a remote hit (at least potentially) in many production deployments, which... has tradeoffs: do the generation work less, but spend more retrieving and burden a service with what is essentially file serving that really isn't designed for it and doesn't need to do it. If you want it in memory you probably want it local to the Rails process.

Answer (score 1):

You should put cached images into such a directory from where they will be served by the web server. You don't want to use send_data for this - that's too slow.
Also, you'll probably want to ignore that directory in your VCS.